# How to resolve the following error?

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning

I was reading the the chapter on search engines in programming collective intelligence and came across the following code snippet and tried to implement it in IPython. However, I encountered error:

```
def getmatchrows(self,q):
    fieldlist='w0.urlid'
    tablelist=''
    clauselist=''
    wordids=[]

    words=q.split()
    tablenumber=0

    for word in words:
        wordrow=self.con.execute("select rowid from wordlist where word='%s'" % word).fetchone()
        if wordrow!=None:
            wordid=wordrow[0]
            wordids.append(wordid)
            if tablenumber>0:
                tablelist+=','
                clauselist+=' and '
                clauselist+='w%d.urlid=w%d.urlid and '%(tablenumber-1,tablenumber)
            fieldlist+=',w%d.location'%tablenumber
            tablelist+='wordlocation w%d'%tablenumber
            clauselist+='w%d.wordid=%d'%(tablenumber,wordid)
            tablenumber+=1
    fullquery="SELECT %s FROM %s WHERE %s"%(fieldlist,tablelist,clauselist)
    cur=self.con.execute(fullquery)
    rows=[row for row in cur]
    return row,wordids
```

I got the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-e5fade95f22f> in <module>()
----> 1 e.getmatchrows('data analysis')

C:\Users\Blue\Anaconda\searchengine.pyc in getmatchrows(self, q)
    128                                         tablelist+=','
    129                                         clauselist+=' and '
--> 130                                         clauselist+='w%d.urlid=w%d.urlid and '%tablenumber-   1,tablenumber
131                                 fieldlist+=',w%d.location'%tablenumber
132                                 tablelist+='wordlocation w%d'%tablenumber

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'tuple'
```

Comment: In the trace, after the `%` there is no parenthesis, is this normal?

Comment: Hey did you downvote this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put parantheses at line 130:

```
tablenumber-1,tablenumber>>(tablenumber1,tablenumber)
```